# Jquery select add values from json

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, json

I have such json:

```
[
{
    "MOD_AXL": 0,
    "MOD_CDS_ID": 110000168,
    "MOD_CV": 0,
    "MOD_CV_CTM": null,
    "MOD_ID": 168,
    "MOD_MFA_ID": 514,
    "MOD_PC": 1,
    "MOD_PCON_END": 199007,
    "MOD_PCON_START": 196303,
    "MOD_PC_CTM": null,
    "Name": "2 CV"},
{
    "MOD_AXL": 0,
    "MOD_CDS_ID": 110004500,
    "MOD_CV": 0,
    "MOD_CV_CTM": null,
    "MOD_ID": 4500,
    "MOD_MFA_ID": 514,
    "MOD_PC": 1,
    "MOD_PCON_END": 198810,
    "MOD_PCON_START": 197808,
    "MOD_PC_CTM": null,
    "Name": "ACADIANE"},
{
    "MOD_AXL": 0,
    "MOD_CDS_ID": 110001660,
    "MOD_CV": 0,
    "MOD_CV_CTM": null,
    "MOD_ID": 1660,
    "MOD_MFA_ID": 514,
    "MOD_PC": 1,
    "MOD_PCON_END": 197712,
    "MOD_PCON_START": 196301,
    "MOD_PC_CTM": null,
    "Name": "AMI"}
// etc..etc..
]​
```

But how to set as select value MOD_ID, and as text of select option: Name?

I have this data in text:

```
$(".man-select").change(function(){
    var mfa_id = $(".man-select").val();
    console.log(mfa_id);
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/get_models_for_mfa/mfa_id="+mfa_id+".json",
      type: "GET", 
      data: {},
      success: function(text)   //here is object
      {
        console.log("getted");
        $('.mod-select')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",text)
         .text(text)); 
      },
      error: function(){
        //alert('Ошибка javascript');
      },
      dataType : "html"
    });      
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may parse your string to JSON format and then iterate though it:

```
success: function(text){
    var your_object = JSON.parse(text);
    $.each(your_object , function(k, item) { 
       $('.mod-select')
             .append($("<option></option>")
             .attr("value", item.MOD_ID)
             .text(item.Name));
    });
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: Just get my latest, it is working ;)... the each have 2 parameters

Comment: also must i change dataType : "json" ?

Comment: My code converts your string to json, so there is no need to do it! If you already have a json, remove the converting line and passes the "text" in the parameter of each directly

Comment: The better option, if you can, is to pass directly a json.

Answer (score 3):

Change `dataType : "html"`   to `dataType : "json"`

Next in the success function do the following changes

```
success: function(text){
    console.log("getted");
    vat html = '' ; 
    $.each(text , function(i){
        html += '<option value="' + text[i]["MOD_ID"] + '">'
                           + text[i]["name"] + '</option>' ;
    }
    $('.mod-select').empty().append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add the values from the returned json list to a `select` list?
If so, this is how I usually do it:

```
var myData = json.d;
var h = [];

$.each(myData, function(i, val) {
    h.push('<option value="' + val.MOD_ID+ '">' + val.Name + '</option>');
});
$('#yourSelect').empty().append(h.join(''));
```

I push the values to an array first because it's much faster than searching the DOM to append to your select for every item.